# problema con funciones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenos días compañeros me podrían decir que error tiene mi código al ejecutarlo siempre lo que hay en el "except ValueError" ya lo he intentado hacer de otras formas y no me da este es mi codigo:

```
#-*coding:utf-8-*-

'''7. Construir una función que reciba como parámetro un carácter y retorne el código ASCII
asociado a él'''

def codigo_ascii(valor):
    valor=int(valor)

    return(valor)

def main():
    try:
        letra=str(input("Digite un caracter :"))
        caracter=codigo_ascii(letra)
        print(caracter)

    except ValueError:
        print("El valor digitado no puede ser numerico")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ya hay una funcion para eso, y se llama ord y si lo quieres al revez tienes la funcion chr

Comment: Tu código está mal indentado y no sabemos si es al pegarlo acá o está así

Comment: Fue al pegarlo aquí la verdad las veces que lo pego se mueve todo no se como hacer que quede igual de ordenado como lo tenia

Comment: @Andress115 http://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo @Eugeni Bejan, lo siguiente debiese bastar:

```
def main():
    try:
        letra=input("Digite un caracter: ")
        caracter=ord(letra)
        print(caracter)

    except ValueError:
        print("El valor digitado no puede ser numerico")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Un detalle. Sobra el `str()` alrededor de `input()`, pues en Python3 la función `input()` devuelve siempre una cadena.

Comment: Gracias abufalia; Corregido.